# C++ Builder - Using same Event TWICE

Tags: c++, events, c++builder, chess

I have a problem and I don't understand where I'm going wrong. My program doesn't show any compiler errors.

I am working at a chess project. When I click on a piece, I want an ID to be remembered. When I click on the Board, I want to move the piece with that ID. I have 2 black ROOKS, both with different IDs.

Here is the code:

formaJoc.cpp

```
void movePiece(int piece, int col, int row)
{
    int left = rowColToPixel[col];
    int top  = rowColToPixel[row];
    switch (piece)
    {
        case(0): {
            fJoc->BlackRooks1[1]->imPiece->OnMouseDown = fJoc -> bkRook1MouseDown;
            fJoc->BlackRooks1[1]->imPiece->Left=left;
            fJoc->BlackRooks1[1]->imPiece->Top=top;
            break;
        }
        case(1): {
            fJoc->BlackRooks2[1]->imPiece->OnMouseDown = fJoc -> bkRook2MouseDown;
            fJoc->BlackRooks2[1]->imPiece->Left=left;
            fJoc->BlackRooks2[1]->imPiece->Top=top;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void __fastcall TfJoc::bkRook1MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
    TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    id = 0;
}

void __fastcall TfJoc::bkRook2MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
    TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    id = 1;
}

void __fastcall TfJoc::imBoardMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
    TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    if (id != 99) {
        col = (X - 40) / 36;
        row = (Y - 40) / 36;
        //movePiece(id, col, row);
        //id=99;
        ShowMessage(id);
    }
}
```

formaJoc.h

```
bkRook*   BlackRooks1[1];
bkRook*   BlackRooks2[1];

void __fastcall TfJoc::bkRook1MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
    TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
void __fastcall TfJoc::bkRook2MouseDown(TObject *Sender,
    TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);

void __fastcall imBoardMouseDown(TObject *Sender,
    TMouseButton Button, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y);
```

When I run the program and click on ROOK 1, ID is set to 0. When I click on ROOK 2, ID is still 0. Why is it not 1? Why does it take the same ID?

Comment: Why are you using 1-element arrays? And where is `ID` defined? And why are you using separate `OnMouseDown` event handlers? You can use one handler, its `Sender` parameter tells you which piece is being clicked. I would suggest storing the ID numbers in each image's `Tag` property, and then you can use `ID = static_cast<TImage*>(Sender)->Tag;` Personally, I wouldn't use ID numbers, I would use the actual piece object pointers instead.

Comment: I'm using 1-element arrays because I only have 1 piece to show on board. ID is defined in formaJoc.cpp. How can I use the actual piece object pointers?

Comment: By the way, when there are no *compiler* errors and your program *doesn't work*, you should **use a debugger** to step through your program, one statement at a time.

Comment: In the `switch` statement of your `movePiece` function, the `case`s have duplicate code.  Move the duplicate code to before the `switch` statement.  Removing duplicate code means less code that can go wrong and less code that you have to test (which saves you development time).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews What exactly do I need to move before the switch statement?

Comment: My bad.  The code looks too similar.  I highly recommend you using a `vector` instead of having `BlackRooks1` and `BlackRooks2`.  If you use a `vector` you'll be able to simplify your code and employ more *generic* programming techniques.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sorry man, I am newbie and I need to finish this project next week. Only if u show me how and where to write it I can make it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't know why, but if I want to move a piece, the next piece moves so I wrote movePiece(id-1, col, row). Is it ok too if I make a class for each piece and make an event like that? I have only 1 class of black pawns and they are 8. I can make 8 classes for each of black pawn and it might work. What do you say?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Each piece is working fine except the first one with id=0, because I have movePiece(id-1, col, row). If I put just id, it will move the next piece. What to do?